# Write Ember Octane Component test to check if state is correct after I submit a form?

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, integration-testing, ember-octane

I want to write a test such that when I submit a string, then a @tracked array =[0,0,0] field will change.
I have a simple `<Textarea @value={{ input0 }} ></Textarea>` for hbs.
if input is `1` then the tracked array becomes `[0,1,0]`.  How do I do this??  So far I have the following code that DOESN'T work:

```
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { setupRenderingTest } from 'ember-qunit';
import { click, render } from '@ember/test-helpers';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

module('Integration | Component | array', function(hooks) {
    setupRenderingTest(hooks);



    test('Textarea should display PLACE [0,1,0]"', async function(assert) {

        await render(hbs`<Array />`);
        assert.equal(find('textarea').value, 'testing"')
      });

});
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding all the pieces of this. Could you include the JS for the component? Also is your component named `Array`? I would avoid that if I were you, there is an `array` helper in ember and while it shouldn't conflict, it's adding just a little bit of friction that could be avoided.

Comment: @jrjohnson im just trying to learn and test a simple component.  The component is ```export default class Array extends Component {@tracked test = 0}```

Comment: And where does the value `input0` fit into that?

Comment: @jrjohnson if input0 = 0 then tracked array becomes [1,0,0], if input0=1, then array = [0,1,0], and if input0=2 then array=[0,0,1]

Comment: @Noob2321 you should not test the tracked property directly. That's internal state of your addon. An implementation detail. Your tests should cover the user facing API which is the DOM.

Comment: @jelhan can I test the state after I submit an input in my hbs for my component?

Comment: @Noob2321 In most cases you want to check a) that the DOM after submit is as expected and b) that an action that should be called on submit is executed with correct arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

It looks like you are being trolled by `window.find`, which isn't what you want, you need `find` from `@ember/test-helpers`.

Replace:

`import { click, render } from '@ember/test-helpers';`

with:

`import { click, find, render } from '@ember/test-helpers';`

Good Luck!